# I am getting a lot of errors in Spring Boot framework

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

Here's the error I am getting :

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.3)

2021-04-11 23:44:53.501  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.LibraryApplication      : Starting LibraryApplication using Java 15.0.2 on LAPTOP-SL7RT9CR with PID 7012 (C:\Users\LINDANI\Library\target\classes started by LINDANI in C:\Users\LINDANI\Library)
2021-04-11 23:44:53.506  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.LibraryApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-11 23:44:53.506 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.example.demo.LibraryApplication
2021-04-11 23:44:54.050 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/Users/LINDANI/Library/target/classes/]
2021-04-11 23:44:54.050 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.settings.DevToolsSettings        : Included patterns for restart : []
2021-04-11 23:44:54.050 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.settings.DevToolsSettings        : Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-starter/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-devtools/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-actuator/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/(bin|build|out)/]
2021-04-11 23:44:54.050  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-04-11 23:44:54.050  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-04-11 23:44:54.050 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@b77404b
2021-04-11 23:44:57.930  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-11 23:44:58.142  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 173 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-04-11 23:45:00.254 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\LINDANI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.4.3\spring-boot-2.4.3.jar
2021-04-11 23:45:00.254 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\LINDANI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.4.3\spring-boot-2.4.3.jar
2021-04-11 23:45:00.259 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.
2021-04-11 23:45:00.537  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-04-11 23:45:00.587  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-11 23:45:00.587  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
2021-04-11 23:45:00.978  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-11 23:45:00.980 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2021-04-11 23:45:00.980  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6930 ms
2021-04-11 23:45:01.009 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping filters: characterEncodingFilter urls=[/*] order=-2147483648, formContentFilter urls=[/*] order=-9900, requestContextFilter urls=[/*] order=-105
2021-04-11 23:45:01.014 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping servlets: dispatcherServlet urls=[/]
2021-04-11 23:45:01.124 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured for use
2021-04-11 23:45:01.124 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.w.s.f.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured for use
2021-04-11 23:45:01.124 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedFormContentFilter     : Filter 'formContentFilter' configured for use
2021-04-11 23:45:02.337  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-04-11 23:45:02.694  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.28.Final
2021-04-11 23:45:03.244  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-11 23:45:03.539  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-11 23:45:05.594  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-04-11 23:45:05.636  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-04-11 23:45:07.817  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-04-11 23:45:07.845  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-11 23:45:07.875 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.livereload.LiveReloadServer      : Starting live reload server on port 35729
2021-04-11 23:45:07.875  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-04-11 23:45:08.217  WARN 7012 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookserviceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookrepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookrepo' defined in com.example.demo.repo.Bookrepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface com.example.demo.repo.Bookrepo
2021-04-11 23:45:08.217  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-11 23:45:08.240  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-04-11 23:45:08.260  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-04-11 23:45:08.265  INFO 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-04-11 23:45:08.275 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Creating new Restarter for thread Thread[main,5,main]
2021-04-11 23:45:08.275 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Immediately restarting application
2021-04-11 23:45:08.275 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@434a0335
2021-04-11 23:45:08.275 DEBUG 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Starting application com.example.demo.LibraryApplication with URLs [file:/C:/Users/LINDANI/Library/target/classes/]
2021-04-11 23:45:08.407 ERROR 7012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookserviceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookrepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookrepo' defined in com.example.demo.repo.Bookrepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface com.example.demo.repo.Bookrepo
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.example.demo.LibraryApplication.main(LibraryApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookrepo' defined in com.example.demo.repo.Bookrepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface com.example.demo.repo.Bookrepo
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface com.example.demo.repo.Bookrepo
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:229) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:179) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:162) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:281) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 36 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here's the pom file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Library</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Make sure your bookrepo class or interface is annotated. @Autowired is not working in bookserviceimpl class.

Comment: How is your class  'com.example.demo.repo.Bookrepo' annotated?

Comment: The implementation of your `BooKRepo` is wrong. It references a repository where it should reference an `@Entity`.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure Your Repository class is annotated with `@Repository`.

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer>{
    }
```

Check your service implementation class and annotate with `@Service` annotation.
Use `@Autowired` while creating objects of repository class in the service implementation class.

```
 @Service
public class BookServiceImplementation implements CommentService{

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

 }
```

Comment: Annotating the interface with `@Repository` is pretty much useless.